# make first letter caps in php but ucfirst(strtolower('string')) does not work

Tags: php, html, string, laravel, uppercase

I've been trying to make the first letter of a string in the capital but I can't get it to work.

I have tried the following code:

```
 <?php

$str = $_POST['Papier'];

$f = highlightKeywords('papierwaren', $str);
$s = strtolower($f);
$r = ucfirst($s);

function highlightKeywords($text, $keyword)
{

    $pos = strpos($text, $keyword);

    $wordsAry = explode(" ", $keyword);

    $wordsCount = count($wordsAry);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $wordsCount; $i++) {
        if ($pos === false) {
            $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . strtolower($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
        } else {
            $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . $wordsAry[$i] . "</span>";
        }
        $text = str_ireplace($wordsAry[$i], $highlighted_text, $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

still, I am not getting it to work and I tried if whitespace occurs with the following

$r=ucfirst(trim($s));

still not succeeded. This 'papierwaren' text i'm getting it form db so pls someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: the $str is any keyword related to the papierwaren that we use in search box for example pap or papier or Papier and so on.

Comment: Convert in conditions

Comment: there also i tried it does not work too...@SahilGupta

Comment: You seem to add html to your string (`<span ...`). When you use `ucfirst` it changes the first char to uppercase but the first char is now `<`, unfortunately (or fortunately?), the uppercase for `<` is `<`. Try to add `ucfirst` inside `highlightKeywords` function

Comment: @Kaddath $highlighted_text or just inside the highlightKeywords function like for the $text?

Comment: It's actually not very clear to me what each variable's value can be, as there is no example, And I'm not sure if you want to capitalize each keyword or just the first char of the whole result (or else I would have added an answer). But I think you should use `ucfirst` where you concatenate your html

Comment: i just want to capitalize the first letter of the whole senetence or the word just only one char @Kaddath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Kaddath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7393478/kaddath) said, You are adding HTML to your string (<span ...). When you use ucfirst it changes the first char to uppercase but the first char is now <, the uppercase for < is <.

**Try this code:**

```
<?php

$str = 'papier';

$f = highlightKeywords('papierwaren', $str);

echo $f;

function highlightKeywords($text, $keyword)
{

    $pos = strpos($text, $keyword);

    $wordsAry = explode(" ", $keyword);

    $wordsCount = count($wordsAry);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $wordsCount; $i++) {
        if ($pos === false) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . ucfirst(strtolower($wordsAry[$i])) . "</span>";
            } else {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . strtolower($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
            }
        } else {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . ucfirst($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
            } else {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . $wordsAry[$i] . "</span>";
            }
        }
        $text = str_ireplace($wordsAry[$i], $highlighted_text, $text);
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: hi , as you suggested i tried to work with your code.It really worked well but the keyword in between any other words became uppercased of first letter so i tried the following by just removing the ucfirst in else part and adding the strtolower.

Comment: else {
             if ($i === 0) {
                 $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . strtolower($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
             } else {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . $wordsAry[$i] . "</span>";
            }
        }

Comment: i'm getting the error like this . When i type the word 'Cup a Soup' it shows some code like the following but not for other words->' an style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>cupan> a Soup'

Answer (score -1):

In laravel this should help

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$testString = 'this is a sentence.';

$uppercased = Str::ucfirst($testString);
```

Do not forget to import `Illuminate\Support\Str` to controller.