# getting the code executed error while trying to highlight some words in php

Tags: php, html, function, loops, highlight

I tried to execute some words together to get those words highlighted. But the problem is sometimes but not all the times the code is being executed.
The code that i used are here:

```
function highlightKeywords($text, $keyword) {
  
    $pos = strpos($text, $keyword);

    $wordsAry = explode(" ", $keyword);
    
    $wordsCount = count($wordsAry);
        
    for ($i = 0; $i < $wordsCount; $i++) {
        if ($pos === false) {
            if ($i === 0) {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . ucfirst(strtolower($wordsAry[$i])) . "</span>";
            } else {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . strtolower($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
            }
        } else {
             if ($i === 0) {
                 $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . strtolower($wordsAry[$i]) . "</span>";
             } else {
                $highlighted_text = "<span style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>" . $wordsAry[$i] . "</span>";
            }
        }
        $text = str_ireplace($wordsAry[$i], $highlighted_text, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

here the $text is the whole text that i pass and the $keyword is the word or words that i want to highlight.Here i had some doubt of making the first letter capital that i made by asking question [make first letter caps in php but ucfirst(strtolower('string')) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710946/make-first-letter-caps-in-php-but-ucfirststrtolowerstring-does-not-work/62711579#62711579) . But from this solution only i rearranged my code that is above. But the problem i face is when i pass `$text='Vegetarische cup a Soup'` and `$keyword='cup a soup'` i get the following code being executed:

```
Vegetarische an style='font-weight:700;color:#151313;'>cupan> a Soup
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: @gpl  if the code works fine then why does it executes the code in between instead of highlighting the keyword?

Comment: @kerbh0lz if we type a sentence then the sentence also wanted to be highlighted and if it is a single word then that word should be highlighted

Comment: @RiggsFolly it produces no error.

Comment: @RiggsFolly can't edit it :/ so I deleted it

Comment: @gpl finally i made it to work.if anybody wishes i can point out where it is.

Comment: sure, we wana know. Check out my code also and use which ever you like :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that i had used in my code from [tomelliott.com](https://tomelliott.com/php/highlight-search-keyword-string-function?unapproved=601270&moderation-hash=20a5abbf7d093139c21ba48c793baf55#comment-601270)

```
function highlightkeywords($str, $search) {
    //$highlightcolor = "#daa732";
    $occurrences = substr_count(strtolower($str), strtolower($search));
    $newstring = $str;
    $match = array();
 
    for ($i=0;$i<$occurrences;$i++) {
        $match[$i] = stripos($str, $search, $i);
        $match[$i] = substr($str, $match[$i], strlen($search));
        $newstring = str_replace($match[$i], '[#]'.$match[$i].'[@]', strip_tags($newstring));
    }
 
    $newstring = str_replace('[#]', '<span style="font-weight:700;color:#151313;">', $newstring);
    $newstring = str_replace('[@]', '</span>', $newstring);
    return $newstring;
 
}
```

here i can escape the html tags as well as has the answer for my other question in stackoverflow for maintaining the case sensitivity [make first letter caps in php but ucfirst(strtolower('string')) does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710946/make-first-letter-caps-in-php-but-ucfirststrtolowerstring-does-not-work/62711579#62711579)

Comment: Striping tag is indeed a good feature but we don't need to lowercase text to as we can do case insensitive comparison. It will add only extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function. Hope it will help. You can change CSS as you wish.

```
<style>
    #keyword{
        font-weight: bold;
        color: red;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<?php
    function highlightKeywords($keyword, $text) {
        $filteredKeyword = trim(strip_tags($keyword));
        $wordsAry = explode(" ", $text);
        $wordsCount = count($wordsAry);
        
        for ($i = 0; $i < $wordsCount; $i++)
            if(strcasecmp($filteredKeyword, $wordsAry[$i]) == 0)
                $wordsAry[$i] = "<span id=\"keyword\">" . $wordsAry[$i] . "</span>";
        
        return implode(" ", $wordsAry);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.I got the required answer from  https://tomelliott.com/php/highlight-search-keyword-string-function?unapproved=601270&moderation-hash=20a5abbf7d093139c21ba48c793baf55#comment-601270

Comment: here what i had to do was just escape the html tags from the function.Cause the case als need to be considered

Comment: Lol, why not you mentioned it :P You said you want to highlight text. I think I deserve an upvote atleast as I answered what you asked. BTW that code seems bit more tricky as it mixes CSS n PHP. I strongly recommend you to not mix them.